# Getting HTTP 404 Error when Web Scraping in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm receiving a 404 error code **(shown below)** when trying to web scrape a certain website.

I've tried looking for answers on different forums but couldn't find a solution

***Anyone have a solution to fix this 404 error?***

The Website URL is https://www.transfermarkt.com/stoke-city/startseite/verein/512/saison_id/2018.

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
>>> from urllib.request import Request
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
>>> my_url = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/stoke-city/startseite/verein/512/saison_id/2018"
>>> uClient = uReq(my_url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\King Carmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\King Carmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Users\King Carmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Users\King Carmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Users\King Carmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\King Carmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: You can add text instead of image.

Comment: @DipankarNalui I've edited the post and included the text

Comment: seems, the problem is with the URL. Could you please check with any other URL.

Comment: seems, problem with SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass user-agent header

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/stoke-city/startseite/verein/512/saison_id/2018'
res  = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(res.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('html'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but if someone like me came to this post by using "scrapy shell" in the console as a client, the solution would be as follows:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0' "https://www.transfermarkt.com/stoke-city/startseite/verein/512/saison_id/2018"
```

It is necessary to specify an user agent.

Answer (score -1):

**This URL does not support `HTTPS`, try changing it to `HTTP`, should work.**

```
>>> my_url = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/stoke-city/startseite/verein/512/saison_id/2018"
```

Using my browser, I wasn't able to open https version but http works fine.

Comment: Strange. I was able to open it on my mobile with HTTPS but not on my laptop.

Answer (score -1):

try using [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) library

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

link = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/stoke-city/startseite/verein/512/saison_id/2018"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(link)
```

shows I get a response 200. OK.

```
In  [01]: print (r)
Out [01]: <Response [200]>
```